# mongoDB - URL as document ID

Tags: mongodb, schema

Considering I want to create mongoDB documents for a bunch of distinct URLs: what would be the pros and cons (if any) of using the actual URL as the documents **_id** value instead of the default **BSON ObjectId**. Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Greg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An overview of the subject here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs

It has to be unique, you could potentially put yourself in the position of having to resolve collisions yourself. Better to leave the default _id alone and simply query against a field you're storing in the document, just how God (10gen) intended.

From http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON

> The element name "_id" is reserved for use as a primary key id, but
>   you can store anything that is unique in that field. The database
>   expects that drivers will prevent users from creating documents that
>   violate these constraints.

From #mongodb

> stupid _id values will probably make querying slow, but that's about it

And another user from #mongodb

> Tell him the collisions will result in garbage data

Comment: Makes sense. :) I'll stick with _id as ObjectID and an index on the url field. Thanks.

Comment: Your proposal is perfect. Indices were made precisely for this sort of thing. Good luck!